# Selenium with .NET Core does not show browser in release mode and ignore options

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the below code to open a selenium driver with Chrome.
The first problem is `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag is not working at all either with debug mode or release mode.

Also, the main problem is when I publish my code with release mode and deploy another machine (Win 10 Pro) the app does not show the browser.
Edit: I think this is not clear selenium working fine but is hidden in some cases we need to display it for user input.

I also have an issue to play audio files automatically and the solutions I found on the internet are not working as well. Throwing JS error saying no click detected.

Is there a way to open a browser with full control? another browser for example firefox etc.

```
        public static IWebDriver GetHeadless()
        {
            ChromeOptions cOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            cOptions.AddArgument("user-agent=SeleniumTests");
            cOptions.AddArgument("--allow-file-access-from-files");
 
            //cOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
            return new ChromeDriver(cOptions);
        }
```

Thanks

EDIT: I am able to manage to run audio by using different options

```
cOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
cOptions.AddArguments("--kiosk");
```

However, the main problem still continues. When deployed in release mode to another PC it is not showing the browser.

The weird thing is when I run the app using VS debug mode it displays the browser for both deployed PC and the Dev PC.

I wonder if is there anything else that needs to be installed beforehand.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-csharp-tutorial.html)?

Comment: @AmirTahan i did not but that doc is just for starting point. I dont have issues running it and everything works fine. except for a couple of issues I mentioned.

Comment: I believe that flag is very old and is no longer supported.  Why did you need it?  There is a file api you could use.  I would make a separate thread for the audio file thing and include the code you're using.